# PHP redirect script

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect my site visitors form page B using my custom PHP script following this rule: If they come from page A, will be redirected to url 1, else i will display content/or url 2. I use this:

```
 <?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$rest = substr("$referer", -8);
if($rest == "send.php﻿")// if they come from my website page "send.php"
{
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://google.com\">"; 
}
else
{
echo "$rest";
include 'content.php'; 
}
?>
```

.
Anyone can help?

Comment: why you can't use header and then check?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($referer,'send.php') !== false) 
{
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://google.com\">"; 
}
else
{
echo "$rest";
include 'content.php'; 
}
?>
```

Instead of meta redirect you can also use header location.

```
header("Location:http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thx, i use meta redirect because i want to keep the referer.